# What is the use of declaring a function which takes and return "ostream&" rather than overloading operator<<?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've come across functions that, rather than overloading the operator << to use with cout, declare a function that takes an ostream and returns an ostream

Example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
private:
  int number;
public:
  A(int n) : number(n) {}
  ~A() {}
  std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const;
  friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A a);
};
```

An example of implementation:

```
std::ostream& A::print(std::ostream& os) const {
  os << "number " << number;
  return os;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A a) {
  os << "number " << a.number;
  return os;
}
```

Now if I run this I can use the different functions in different situations.. E.g.

```
int main() {
  A a(1);

  std::cout << "Object.";  a.print(std::cout);
  std::cout << "\n\n";
  std::cout << "Object." << a;
  std::cout << "\n\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Object.number 1

Object.number 1
```

There doesn't seem to be a situation where the print function would be needed since you could only use separately or in the beginning of a "cout chain" but never in the middle or end of it which perhaps makes it useless. Wouldn't it (if no other use is found) be better off using a function "void print()" instead?

Comment: The use is to really annoy me. I can't see any valid reason for this.

Comment: That isn't quite correct.  You can nest the function instead of chaining it.  `a.print(std::cout << "Object.");`

Comment: I'd be very peeved by `a.print(a.print(std::cout << "before" ) << "in between" ) << "after";`. though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would make a lot more sense if `operator<<()` actually looked like

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const A a) {
    return a.print(os);
}
```

Then `operator<<()` wouldn't need to be a friend.

Comment: Thank you for the code example. This makes perfect sense, your way of answering a question is a bit strange though :) If it wasn't for the fact that it is under "Answers" I would have considered it more of a comment on my example ;)

Answer (score 7):

It would make sense where an inheritance hierarchy comes in to play. You can make the `print` method virtual, and in the operator for the base class, delegate to the virtual method to print.

Comment: Thanks. Even thought it doesn't need to be virtual and should be used as Ernest wrote in the other answer I understood your point. It helped a lot, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A function that *can* be used as the start of a cout chain certainly sounds more useful than one that *can't*, all other things being equal.

I've implemented several functions with signatures like you describe because `operator<<` is only one name, and sometimes I need to have objects streamed in multiple different ways. I have one format for printing to the screen, and another format for saving to a file. Using `<<` for both would be non-trivial, but choosing a human-readable name for at least one of the operations is easy.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `operator<<` assumes that there is only one sensible way to print data.  And sometimes that is true.  But sometimes there are multiple valid ways to want to output data:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout; using std::endl;
int main()
{
  const char* strPtr = "what's my address?";
  const void* address = strPtr;

  // When you stream a pointer, you get the address:
  cout << "Address: " << address << endl;

  // Except when you don't:
  cout << "Not the address: " << strPtr << endl;
}
```

http://codepad.org/ip3OqvYq

In this case, you can either chose one of the ways as *the way*, and have other functions (`print`?) for the rest.  Or you can just use `print` for all of them.  (Or you might use stream flags to trigger which behavior you want, but that's harder to set up and use consistently.)